# How does a Stargate get closed?

Tags: stargate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Closing the Stargate Wormhole](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8628/closing-the-stargate-wormhole)

Okay, I've watched many an episode of Stargate, but I can't for the life of me figure out how a Stargate gets closed. I know a few specific methods, which include:

1. If the time limit runs out (38 minutes)
2. If there isn't enough power on the sending end.

But I can't for the life of me figure out the general method. Anyone know off hand?

Answer (score 0):

Based on answers to " [Closing the Stargate Wormhole](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8628/closing-the-stargate-wormhole) " (as well as more Googling), there just doesn't seem to be enough canon information. The best theory (NOT proven by canon) seems to be:

- StarGate control has a way to **keep the gate open**, via some signal/power
- It will only close when either 39 minutes pass,

  OR

  when that "keep open" signal is stopped AND there's nothing in transit/near the gate.

But basically there seem to be no firm rules (even "nothing in transit" is violated in "Enemy within" when someone gets killed via beheading by Stargate).

Comment: That last rule isn't "nothing in transit", it's "nothing is part way though the event horizon".  The SGC's Stargate is an exception to that particular rule because they can cut all power to their Stargate, shutting it down despite safeguards (except in extraordinary circumstances, like the excess power from a black hole).