# When do Stargates close?

Tags: stargate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Closing the Stargate Wormhole](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8628/closing-the-stargate-wormhole)

I've seen numerous scenes where they're on another planet and dial to another stargate, the gate opens, it waits for each and every team member to pass and then closes. How does the gate know when to close and when to wait? From my understanding the gates remain open as long as matter passes through them so can't wind keep them open?

Answer (score 2):

I guess an Ancient engineer hooked a motion sensor to the front of it. So it stays open as long as someone is in the proximity :)

Seriously though, IIRC it was mentioned in one episode that the Stargate will stay open as long as a signal is being sent. So just sending a radio signal will keep it open.

Comment: ...but the universe is full of radio signals and echoes of the bigbang and stuff

Comment: check out this question on [closing the stargate wormhole](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8628/closing-the-stargate-wormhole)